# Azure Windows VM - RDP issues

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I currently need to run some windows-specific software for part of a workflow, and I can't run it on my personal computer.

I have got the free account at Azure, so I thought I would use the remote windows machine. I created the VM, and I can see the login screen on Boot Diagnostics.

However, I can't connect to RDP. Tried several issues and solutions (all provided on Azure docs), to no avail.

A few steps I already did:

1. Checked network configs. Tried different external ports for RDP (if somehow the RDP port could be blocked somewhere). I also tried basic configuration, advanced configuration.
2. Re-created the external IP's. The machine can't be pinged, and I don't seem to be able to trace routes for them.
3. Re-deployed the machine, deleted and created a new machine.
4. Switched and tried different Linux RDP connectors, and even used a friends Windows computer to try to connect, to no avail.

I could gladly use any help troubleshooting this.

My machine is currently running Linux Mint, on the eduroam Wifi networks.

Thanks in advance, and feel free to ask for any additional information or configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly, you could check if the RDP port is blocked on NSG(vm nic level or subnet level NSG), you could follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) to open the port. 
[image]

Also, you could verify if the networking connectivity issue from your local computer to Azure following by Using [Telnet to Test Port 3389 Functionality](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/187628/using-telnet-to-test-port-3389-functionality). For example, run `telnet  VMpublicIP 3389` in CMD as the administrator account.

If the RDP port is already enabled in NSG, see [Troubleshoot an RDP general error in Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-general-error) and [Troubleshoot Azure VM RDP connection issues by Event ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/event-id-troubleshoot-vm-rdp-connecton)

Comment: I had already tried this. Brought the computer home and could connect. Probably it is the eduroam network blocking - even when I change RDP to port 80 (to look like no-rdp traffic) it still doesnt work. I guess it is a network issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, probably the outbound RDP is blocking in the eduroam network. Basically, you could verify it using telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Tried on another network and it worked. It seems eduroam blocks RDP even when it is on other ports.